# How to save a modified array to a file

Tags: c, arrays

So I created an array which is saved in a file. I have the number 4 printed out 100 times in the file. Now everytime the an element in the array is accessed it the value will decrease by 1. So if A[1] = 4 is accessed then it will become A[1] = 3 and be saved on the file. The thing is I can't save the modified array to the file.

I already tried moving the placement of FILE pointer.

```
void buildingB4()
{
    system("CLS");
    FILE *input, *output;
    int i, B4[100], room;

    input = fopen("B4.txt", "r");
    if (input == NULL)
    {
        output = fopen("B4.txt", "w");
        for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            B4[i] = 4;
            fprintf(output, "%d\n", B4[i]);
        }
        fclose(output);
        for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            if (i % 10 == 0)
            {
                printf("\n\n");
            }
            printf("B-4-%d(%d)\t", i, B4[i]);
        }
    }
    else
    {

        for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            fscanf(input, "%d\n", &B4[i]);
            if (i % 10 == 0)
            {
                printf("\n\n");
            }
            printf("B-4-%d(%d)\t", i, B4[i]);
        }
        fclose(input);
        printf("\nPlease choose a room:B-4-");
        scanf("%d", &room);
        B4[room] = B4[room] - 1;
        output = fopen("B4.txt", "a");
        fprintf(output, "%d\n", B4[i]);
        studentDetails();
    }
}
```

say if A[1] = 4
and when user input is 1, 1 is saved in a variable called room.
so A[room] = A[room] -1 
so the result would be A[1] = 3 and it modify the A[1] saved in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Use fclose after the line 
 fprintf(output, "%d\n", B4[i]);

Answer (score 0):

I've found little mistakes in your code and here is your fixed code:

```
#define HOME_SIZE 100
void show_rooms(int B[]){
    for (int i = 0; i < HOME_SIZE; i++){
            if (i % 10 == 0){
                printf("\n\n");
            }
            printf("B-4-%3d(%d) ", i + 1, B[i]);
        }
}
void buildingB4()
{
    FILE *input, *output;
    input = fopen("B4.txt", "r");
    unsigned int B[HOME_SIZE], room;
    if (input == NULL){
        fclose(input);
        // Setting all homes to 4.
        for (int i = 0; i < HOME_SIZE; ++i){
            B[i] = 4;
        }
        output = fopen("B4.txt", "w");
        for(int i = 0; i < HOME_SIZE; ++i)
            fprintf(output, "%d\n", B[i]);
        fclose(output);
        show_rooms(B);
    }
    else{
        for (int i = 0; i < HOME_SIZE; ++i){
            fscanf(input, "%d", &B[i]);
        }
        fclose(input);
        show_rooms(B);
        printf("\nPlease choose a room:B-4-");
        scanf("%d", &room);
        if (room > 0 && room <= HOME_SIZE)
            B[room - 1] -= 1;
        output = fopen("B4.txt", "w");
        for(int i = 0; i < HOME_SIZE; ++i)
            fprintf(output, "%d\n", B[i]);
    }
}
```

Notice that :

- In C index starts from 0 not 1.
- close using file after your work in order to save it properly.
- Don't use '%d\n' format for scanf, it will ignore ' ' and '\n' automatically.

Tips for future development :

- Try using **feof** function to know if your file is ended or not instead of using constant size for your inputs.